# C# List.Find() seems not working when list is huge

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

I have a huge List, say 10 million items in it, which I'm trying to find a specific value in the list.

Here's my item

```
struct reference
{
    public double GPST;
    public byte cls;
    public ushort fn;
    public int ret_num;
}
```

and here's my query code

```
 List<reference> ref_pts;

 List<reference> result = ref_pts.FindAll(delegate(reference obj) { return obj.GPST == pt.GPST; });
```

where pt.GPST is the value I want to find  in List

Is it just because the size is too big, which Find method not working(always return nothing)?

Comment: Yes, It is. I edit the question, thanks for reminding me this.

Comment: No, the reason is not that list is large. The list has no problem handling data of that size. One reason could be the precision problem of doubles that thumbmunkeys suggest, another is that there would be a problem somewhere else in your code so that the list actually doesn't contain the item that you are looking for.

Comment: I tried to find the item by using for loop, and the item can be found this way. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cant compare doubles for equality like this, use an epsilon to compare against:

```
bool CompareDoubles2 (double A, double B) 
{
   diff = A - B;
   return (diff < EPSILON) && (-diff < EPSILON);
}
```

`EPSILON` is a very small number, for details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404513/floating-point-equality-and-tolerances)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel are you sure? `not doing very well` can be just as about anything

Comment: He is right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I hope OP is talking about performance problems from this phrase `not doing very well`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: OP is talking about "always return nothing", not performance.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Fine, sorry for confusion, btw I withdrawn my downvote

Comment: I'm sorry for my wrong description. It always returns nothing in result list.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys sorry, code is left in my working computer. I'll have to send you a copy tomorrow(it's 8 pm here now)