# Postgresql weird result on having clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
T . ID,
T . NAME,
T .feed_id,
T .status,
T .budget,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT (*)
    FROM
        segment
    WHERE
        segment.campaign_id = T . ID
) AS total_segments,
(
    SELECT
        SUM (revenue)
    FROM
        TRANSACTION
    WHERE
        TRANSACTION .campaign_id = T . ID
    AND TRANSACTION .status = 3
    AND deleted = 0
) AS projected_revenue
  FROM
campaign T
 WHERE
(T .deleted = 0)
AND (site_id = 3)
GROUP BY
T ."id"
  HAVING
  (
    SELECT
        SUM (revenue)
    FROM
        TRANSACTION
    WHERE
        TRANSACTION .campaign_id = T . ID
    AND TRANSACTION .status = 3
    AND deleted = 0
    ) > 242.45
      ORDER BY
  T . ID DESC
```

The query works fine when `having` subquery is greater than (`>`) or less than (`<`) but when equals it does not show any result. But it works with:

```
HAVING (
  SELECT SUM (revenue)
  FROM TRANSACTION 
  WHERE TRANSACTION.campaign_id = T.ID 
    AND TRANSACTION.status = 3
    AND deleted = 0
)::NUMERIC = 242.45
```

Comment: Could it be that the NUMERIC type specifier lets you compare within a small interval? (`242.45` cannot be represented as a finite binary number.)

Comment: @GáborBakos `NUMERIC` is binary-coded decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, `revenue` is `float4` or `float8`, i.e. a `float` or `double precision` value.

As @GáborBakos accurately noted, some values (including 242.45) do not have an exact binary floating point representation. Observe:

```
regress=> SET extra_float_digits = 3;
SET
regress=> SELECT FLOAT4 '242.45';
   float4   
------------
 242.449997
(1 row)
```

In general, you should not compare floating point values for equality. Use a small range instead.

See:

- http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/
- [How should I do floating point comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915462/398670)
- [Floating point equality and tolerances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17404513/398670)
- http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

Your query works with the cast to `NUMERIC` because, unlike `float4` or `float8`, `NUMERIC` is a binary-coded decimal type with arbitrary precision and scale. It can precisely represent `242.45` and it doesn't suffer from the rounding artifacts and other oddities of floating point maths. However, that cast isn't always going to be enough - other values may still not work how you expect. Consider:

```
regress=> select (float4 '0.3' * 100000000) :: NUMERIC;
     numeric      
------------------
 30000001.1920929
(1 row)
```

As you can see those rounding errors can accumulate.

Rather than rely on comparing with `numeric`, you should really use a small range comparision instead of comparing for equality. Or, best of all, use `numeric` consistently to represent financial and exact quantities, *never* floating point.

Comment: many thanks for this link simple and clear http://www.peterbe.com/plog/comparing-real-values