# Implementing unordered set of triplets

Tags: c++, floating-point, std, unordered-set

I have two 3D data-sets. Each element in these sets is a triplet of type `(float,float,float)`. These data-sets have some *duplicate* elements. I want to *merge* these two data-sets in such a way so that resulting set does not have any duplicate elements.

A naive approach is to simply maintain a list of `std::vector` to store these triplets, any new triplet should be inserted only if it is not already present in the list(checking using simple [floating-point equality comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17404513/985166))

In order to reduce insertion time, another approach can be to store a triplet in a kd-tree only after *querying* for the triplet in the current tree to avoid duplicates.

**Question:**

I would like to know if there are other approaches to *effectively* implement unordered set with floating-point triplet elements?