# C - Zero Double Var not match condition

Tags: c, double

I have this code:

```
typedef struct{
    double tmp;
} MyTime

void foo(double time){
    printf("A: %f\n", time);
    if(time==0)
       printf("B\n");
}

void main(){
    MyTime mytime;
    foo(mytime.tmp);
}
```

The output of the program is only "A: 0.000000". Why its not also printing "B"?

I cannot understanded...

thnx

Comment: Replace `printf("A: %f\n", time);` with the more informative `printf("A: %e\n", time);`.

Comment: Hot tip - uninitialized variables in C aren't necessarily zero.

Comment: @CarlNorum: This is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404513/floating-point-equality-and-tolerances). There is no floating-point rounding in this question, and comparing with a tolerance is not an appropriate solution. The actual problem here is the object was not initialized, so the required solution is to initialize it. Please do not mark questions as duplicates promiscuously based on superficial resemblances.

Comment: When you post code in a question, post exactly the code used. Copy and paste it, do not retype. The missing semicolon in the `typedef` means the code you entered in the question could not be the code you actually compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show fails to initialize `mytime`. In C, an object defined inside a function without `static` is not initialized by default to zero (or any other value). Its value is indeterminate, and using it generally results in undefined behavior.

In this case, the code behaved as if `mytime.tmp` had a small non-zero value, such as 1e-9. When formatted with `%f`, small values are formatted as “0.000000”. And, since the value is not zero, `time==0` returns false. (Changing `%f` to `%g` would likely reveal a small non-zero value.)

Since the code fails to initialize `mytime`, the value in `mytime.tmp` could also have been very large, or the program could have crashed.

Also, the code as posted fails to compile and has a number of issues:

- The `typedef` definition of `MyTime` must be terminated with a semicolon.
- The code should contain `#include <stdio.h>` to declare `print`.
- `main` should be declared `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.